# Datagridview forcing only one checkbox to be selected in a column

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, datagridview, checkbox

How do I force only a single checkbox to be checked in a column of a Datagridview?

Comment: In order to remain consistent with the whole computer software industry, use radio buttons instead of checkboxes.  A list check box mean you can select multiple items, while radio buttons means you can select only one for the group. There can be solution to your problem, but I highly advise you against this direction. If you choose checkboxes instead of radio button because you allow no value, add a radiobutton "none", or a "clear" button to select no option.

Comment: @SteveB I know I'm late to this comment but I don't see a Radio button in Winforms Datagridview?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will have to subscribe for the `CellValueChanged` event of the grid and depending on the check state of the current cell, loop the DataGridView and set true/false as Value for the other cells.

```
void grd_CellValueChanged(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
      if ((sender as DataGridView).CurrentCell is DataGridViewCheckBoxCell)
      {
           if (Convert.ToBoolean(((sender as DataGridView).CurrentCell as DataGridViewCheckBoxCell).Value))
           {
                   // Maybe have a method which does the
                    //loop and set value except for the current cell
            }
        }
}
```

Comment: a client side solution (jquery can help a lot) is fat more preferable, this will avoid dozens of postbacks

Comment: @SteveB Check the tag its **winform**

Comment: @V4Vendetta Just a question, why CellValueChanged instead of CellContentClick? From what I understand, CellValueChanged event is thrown when any of the cells' content is changed but CellContentClick event is thrown when only a certain content in the cell has been clicked (I.E: Checkbox in this case), so wouldn't using CellContentClick event be preferable?

Comment: @SokwhanHuh Its only after Value has changed will it work, Content click might run multiple times while the cell is still in edit, but once the edit is done and through ValueChanged fires, so makes more sense to handle it there. (Also this is not the only way but one of the way)

Comment: CellValueChanged Method works any kind of cell, but CellContentClick works only valid grid.

Answer (score 5):

```
 private void grdRegClass_CellContentClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
    {
        if (grdRegClass.Columns.IndexOf(grdRegClass.Columns["Status"]) == e.ColumnIndex)
        {
            int currentcolumnclicked = e.ColumnIndex;
            int currentrowclicked = e.RowIndex;
            foreach (DataGridViewRow dr in grdRegClass.Rows)
            {
                dr.Cells[currentcolumnclicked].Value = false;
            }
            grdRegClass.CurrentRow.Cells[currentrowclicked].Value = true;  
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

```
    private void dataGridViewProduit_CellValueChanged(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
    {
        if ((sender as DataGridView).CurrentCell is DataGridViewCheckBoxCell)
        {
            if (Convert.ToBoolean(((sender as DataGridView).CurrentCell as DataGridViewCheckBoxCell).Value))
            {
                foreach (DataGridViewRow row in (sender as DataGridView).Rows)
                {
                    if (row.Index != (sender as DataGridView).CurrentCell.RowIndex && Convert.ToBoolean(row.Cells[e.ColumnIndex].Value) == true)
                    {
                        row.Cells[e.ColumnIndex].Value = false;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private void dataGridViewClient_CurrentCellDirtyStateChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (this.dataGridViewClient.IsCurrentCellDirty)
        {
            dataGridViewClient.CommitEdit(DataGridViewDataErrorContexts.Commit);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `CellEndEdit` event of `DGV`, as it occurs after when the cell is modified. Kindly read the comments in below code snippet to use the code below:

```
private void dgrvUserProfileView_CellEndEdit(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
    int CheckedCount = 0;

    //Make sure you have set True Value/ false Value property of check box column to 1/0 or true/false resp.
    //Lets say your column 5th(namely Department) is a checked box column
    if (dgrvUserProfileView.Columns[e.ColumnIndex].Name == "Department")
    {
        for (int i = 0; i <= dgrvUserProfileView.Rows.Count - 1; i++)
        {
            if (Convert.ToBoolean(dgrvUserProfileView.Rows[i].Cells["Department"].Value) == true)
            {
                CheckedCount = CheckedCount + 1;
            }
        }

        if (CheckedCount == 1)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i <= dgrvUserProfileView.Rows.Count - 1; i++)
            {
                if (Convert.ToBoolean(dgrvUserProfileView.Rows[i].Cells["Department"].Value) == true)
                {
                    dgrvUserProfileView.Rows[i].Cells["Department"].ReadOnly = true;
                }
            }
        }
        else
        {
            for (int i = 0; i <= dgrvUserProfileView.Rows.Count - 1; i++)
            {
                dgrvUserProfileView.Rows[i].Cells["Department"].ReadOnly = false;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: or take a reference from this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10438613/datagridview-how-can-i-make-a-checkbox-act-as-a-radio-button

Answer (score 0):

```
private void dgvlist_CellContentClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)  
    {  
        int currentcolumnclicked = e.ColumnIndex;  
        for (int i = 0; i <= dgvlist.Columns.Count - 1; i++)  
        {  
            if (dgvlist.Columns[i] is DataGridViewCheckBoxColumn)  
            {  
                if (Convert.ToString(dgvlist.CurrentRow.Cells[i].EditedFormattedValue) == "True" && i !=currentcolumnclicked)  
                {  
                    dgvlist.CurrentRow.Cells[i].Value = false;  
                }  
            }  
        }  
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
private void dgvCaixa_CellContentClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
        {
            if ((sender as DataGridView).CurrentCell is DataGridViewCheckBoxCell)
            {
                foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dgvCaixa.Rows)
                {
                    if (row.Index != dgvCaixa.CurrentCell.RowIndex && Convert.ToBoolean(row.Cells[e.ColumnIndex].Value) == true)
                    {
                        row.Cells[e.ColumnIndex].Value = false;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

in vb.net:

```
Private Sub DataGridViewJobsList_CellValueChanged(sender As Object, e As DataGridViewCellEventArgs) Handles DataGridViewJobsList.CellValueChanged
    If TypeOf TryCast(sender, DataGridView).CurrentCell Is DataGridViewCheckBoxCell Then
        Dim cell1 As DataGridViewCell
        cell1 = TryCast(sender, DataGridView).CurrentCell
        If cell1.Value = True Then
            For Each row As DataGridViewRow In TryCast(sender, DataGridView).Rows
                If row.Index <> cell1.RowIndex AndAlso row.Cells(e.ColumnIndex).Value = "1" Then
                    row.Cells(e.ColumnIndex).Value = False
                End If
            Next
        End If
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub DataGridViewJobsList_CurrentCellDirtyStateChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles DataGridViewJobsList.CurrentCellDirtyStateChanged
    If Me.DataGridViewJobsList.IsCurrentCellDirty Then
        DataGridViewJobsList.CommitEdit(DataGridViewDataErrorContexts.Commit)
    End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set the **VirtualMode** setting to **TRUE** on the **DGV** to allow only one checkbox. and you can set **VirtualMode** setting to **FALSE** on the **DatagridView** to check more than one.

I think this is the easiest way for the solution.

Answer (score 0):

Without worrying about the Column and never fail, try this:

```
private void DgvIVA_CellContentClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
    DataGridView dg = (DataGridView)sender;
    if (dg.Rows.Count == 0) return;
    if (dg.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[e.ColumnIndex].GetType() == typeof(DataGridViewCheckBoxCell))
    {
        int rowSelIndex = e.RowIndex;
        foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dg.Rows)
        {
            if (row.Index != rowSelIndex)
            {
                row.Cells[e.ColumnIndex].Value = false;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score -2):

```
private void dataGridView3_CellContentClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.ColumnIndex == 1)
            {
                try
                {
                    string val = dataGridView3.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[e.ColumnIndex].Value.ToString();
                    if (val == "False")
                        val = "True";
                    else if (val == "True")
                        val = "False";
                    dataGridView3.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[e.ColumnIndex].Value = val;

                for (int i = 0; i < dataGridView3.Rows.Count; i++)
                {
                    string active = "";
                    if (i != e.RowIndex)
                    {
                        if (val == "False")
                        {
                            dataGridView3.Rows[i].Cells[1].Value = "True";
                            active = "Y";
                        }
                        else if (val == "True")
                        {
                            dataGridView3.Rows[i].Cells[1].Value = "False";
                            active = "N";
                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        if (val == "False")
                            active = "N";
                        else
                            active = "Y";
                    }




                }


            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            { }
        }
    }
```