# How to get the total checked checkbox in a single column of gridview and show it into a label

Tags: c#, gridview, checkbox, desktop-application

I need some help. I searched mostly sites but did not find desired code for my query.
I am coding for a module of "Attendance of Class" in window application and here I have a gridview having student name(textbox column), roll no(textbox column), present(checkbox column), absent(checkbox column), on leave(checkbox column).

1. I want only one checkbox should be checked in a row.
2. I want to show the total present student(means total of "present checkbox" column checked checkboxes) in a label names total present students.

Any Suggestion would be appreciated.  [GridView ScreenShot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bahu8.png)

Comment: This would be easier to visualize if you presented it that way. It seems both a "present" and an "absent" checkbox are redundant - if "present" is not checked, they are by default absent.

Comment: Thanks for this nice suggestion but there is "On Leave" status also. So, it looks good if we have different checkboxes for each status of a student i.e. Present, absent or on leave.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this to count all present students (as mentioned in a comment, if someone isn't present then by default they are absent)

```
   int present = 0;
   foreach (DataRow row in Students.Rows)
        {

           if (Student[row][2].Checked)//where i is the column in the datagridview
            {
                present++
            } 
        }
```

As for only having a single box checked, refere to this [Post on StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11466488/datagridview-forcing-only-one-checkbox-to-be-selected-in-a-column)

Comment: Thanks for the help, I found the desired method in Post on StackOverflow for one checked checkbox in a row.
As I tried above code, Please explain me what is "Student" in 
if (Student[row][2].Checked)

Comment: Fantastic. Make sure to give an upvote to the answer on the post i linked if you used it in your solution

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer myself by the following code:
First, I set the checkBox True value set to the 1 and false to 0 in gridview.and apply the following code:-

```
 private int countPresenttudents()
    {
        int d = 0, e = 0;

        for (int i = 0; i < (dgvAttendance.Rows.Count - 1); i++)
        {
            d = Convert.ToInt32(dgvAttendance.Rows[i].Cells["Absent"].Value.ToString());
            e = e + d; //storing total qty into variable 
        }
        return e;
    }
```

and apply it on the lable-

```
private void btnGetTotal_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            lblPresent.Text = Convert.ToString(countpresent());
            lblAbsent.Text = Convert.ToString(countabsent());
            lblLeave.Text=Convert.ToString(countleave());
        }
        catch
        {
        }
    }
```

Comment: Please help just one thing, sometimes cell value is showing null for false and sometime it is 0(as I set 0 in its properties). So, null value can not converted into int.