# prevent user from checking dataGridViewcheckBoxColumn if one selected and store specific cell content in a variable depending on the checked row

Tags: c#, datagridview

Pardon me if my question is not completely clear but I faced this problem in my dataGridView and it is that I have dataGridView that contains the quantities and expire dates of an item that is stored in the inventory .. suppose that I have two quantities of same item but they differ in the expire date and I wnat to sell the older expire date item so I want to check only on that row in dataGridView that contains the older item ,but in my case I can select both rows.
And finally I want to store the expire date cell value of checked row into a string variable to use it in **update query** of the inventory.

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Datagridview forcing only one checkbox to be selected in a column](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11466488/datagridview-forcing-only-one-checkbox-to-be-selected-in-a-column)

Answer (score 0):

The answer was found and tested on my problem and it worked perfectly but still don't know how to store the cell contnet of expire date into a variable

```
private void grdRegClass_CellContentClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
    {
        if (grdRegClass.Columns.IndexOf(grdRegClass.Columns["Status"]) == e.ColumnIndex)
        {
            int currentcolumnclicked = e.ColumnIndex;
            int currentrowclicked = e.RowIndex;
            foreach (DataGridViewRow dr in grdRegClass.Rows)
            {
                dr.Cells[currentcolumnclicked].Value = false;
            }
            grdRegClass.CurrentRow.Cells[currentrowclicked].Value = true;
            string expire= exDatedgv.CurrentRow.Cells["itmexDateCol"].Value.ToString();  
        }
    }
```

The answer was by @Nilantha Ekanayake in this question [Datagridview forcing only one checkbox to be selected in a column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11466488/datagridview-forcing-only-one-checkbox-to-be-selected-in-a-column)
And the code for storing expire date in a string variable added by me as:

```
string expire= exDatedgv.CurrentRow.Cells["itmexDateCol"].Value.ToString();
```