# In datagridview how to use checkbox as radiobutton?

Tags: c#, winforms, checkbox, datagridview

IDE: Visual Studio c#, Winforms Application.

I have invested around 12 hours but didn't get success. As `DataGridView` don't provide radiobutton type of cell. so i am trying to use checkbox cell as radio-buttion functionality.

i.e I want to be checked only one checkbox in a column.

see image:

[image]

It looks very simple thing but trust me it is not as simple as we are thinking. before giving reply please test the code.

Here are my sample tested code which i have tried:

code 1

```
////start
if (e.RowIndex != -1)
{
    if (dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[0].Value != null && dataGridView1.CurrentCell.ColumnIndex == 0) //null check
    {
        if (e.ColumnIndex == 0)
        {
            if (((bool)dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[0].Value == true))
            {

                for (int k = 0; k <= 4; k++)
                {
                    //uncheck all other checkboxes but keep the current as checked
                   if (k == dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Index)
                    {
                        dataGridView1.Rows[k].Cells[0].Value = false;
                 }
                    //if (gvTeam1.Rows[k].Cells[2].Selected != null)
                    //if(k !=e.RowIndex)              

                }

                // gvTeam1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[2].Value = false; // keep the current captain box checked
            }
        }
        //}


        // gvTeam1.Rows[rowPointerTeam1].Cells[2].Value = true;
    }
}
//end
// here gvTeam1 is Datagridview1
```

code 2:
tested on datagridview1

```
private void dataGridView1_CurrentCellDirtyStateChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (dataGridView1.CurrentCell.ColumnIndex == 0)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++)
        {
            //if (i != dataGridView1.CurrentCell.RowIndex)
                dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[0].Value = false;              

        }
        dataGridView1.Rows[dataGridView1.CurrentCell.RowIndex].Cells[0].Value = true;
    }
}
```

Comment: I have answered originally here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10438613/datagridview-how-can-i-make-a-checkbox-act-as-a-radio-button/33537965#33537965

Answer (score 3):

```
    private void dataGridView1_CellContentClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
    {
        //clean al rows
        foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView1.Rows)
        {
            row.Cells["Select"].Value = false;
        }

        //check select row
        dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells["Select"].Value = true;
     }
```

Comment: This allows the user to check same checkbox twice and end up with an unchecked current row (which means no row is checked). This is not the radio button behavior desired by original poster. How to force the current checkbox to stay checked no matter how many times it is clicked?

Answer (score 3):

I know I'm late to the party, but here is code to use actual radio buttons instead of checkboxes.

**Credit:**
Thanks to Arsalan Tamiz's blog post, on which this code is based.
http://arsalantamiz.blogspot.com/2008/09/using-datagridview-checkbox-column-as.html
Also thanks to [M. Viper's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30939962/3508142) for laying some of the ground work.

**Step 1:** Add a DataGridView control to your panel and add a CheckBoxColumn (I named mine `grid` and `colRadioButton` respectively).  I'm not sure if this matters, but the EditMode property of my DataGridView is set to `EditOnEnter`.

**Step 2:** Create an event handler for the CellPainting event.

```
private void grid_CellPainting(object sender, DataGridViewCellPaintingEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.ColumnIndex == colRadioButton.Index && e.RowIndex >= 0)
    {
        e.PaintBackground(e.ClipBounds, true);

        // TODO: The radio button flickers on mouse over.
        // I tried setting DoubleBuffered on the parent panel, but the flickering persists.
        // If someone figures out how to resolve this, please leave a comment.

        Rectangle rectRadioButton = new Rectangle();
        // TODO: Would be nice to not use magic numbers here.
        rectRadioButton.Width = 14;
        rectRadioButton.Height = 14;
        rectRadioButton.X = e.CellBounds.X + (e.CellBounds.Width - rectRadioButton.Width) / 2;
        rectRadioButton.Y = e.CellBounds.Y + (e.CellBounds.Height - rectRadioButton.Height) / 2;

        ButtonState buttonState;
        if (e.Value == DBNull.Value || (bool)(e.Value) == false)
        {
            buttonState = ButtonState.Normal;
        }
        else
        {
            buttonState = ButtonState.Checked;
        }
        ControlPaint.DrawRadioButton(e.Graphics, rectRadioButton, buttonState);

        e.Paint(e.ClipBounds, DataGridViewPaintParts.Focus);

        e.Handled = true;
    }
}
```

**Step 3:** Handle the CurrentCellDirtyStateChanged event to uncheck the previous selection.  This is basically the same as [M. Viper's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30939962/3508142).

```
private void radioButtonChanged()
{
    if (grid.CurrentCell.ColumnIndex == colRadioButton.Index)
    {
        foreach (DataGridViewRow row in grid.Rows)
        {
            // Make sure not to uncheck the radio button the user just clicked.
            if (row.Index != grid.CurrentCell.RowIndex)
            {
                row.Cells[colRadioButton.Index].Value = false;
            }
        }
    }
}

private void grid_CurrentCellDirtyStateChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    radioButtonChanged();
}
```

**Step 4:** (Optional) Handle the CellClick event to allow the user to check the radio button by clicking anywhere in the cell rather than only directly on the radio button.

```
private void grid_CellClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.ColumnIndex == colRadioButton.Index)
    {
        DataGridViewCheckBoxCell cell = (DataGridViewCheckBoxCell)grid.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[colRadioButton.Index];
        cell.Value = true;
        radioButtonChanged();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try This,

```
private void dataGridView1_CellMouseUp(object sender, DataGridViewCellMouseEventArgs e)
{
    UpdateCellValue(e.RowIndex);
}
private void UpdateCellValue(int CurrentRowIndex)
{
    if (CurrentRowIndex < 0)
        return;
    dataGridView1.Rows[CurrentRowIndex].Cells[0].Value = true;
    dataGridView1.EndEdit();
    if (CurrentRowIndex > -1)
    {
        for (int row = 0; row < dataGridView1.Rows.Count; row++)
        {
            if (CurrentRowIndex != row)
                dataGridView1.Rows[row].Cells[0].Value = false;
        }
    }            
}
```

Comment: Not working man. THis code is unchecking all and current checkbox when i am leaving from that cell.

Comment: Now on 5th click i am able to check the checkbox and when moving to next column Its again unChecking  the previous checkbox.

Answer (score 0):

Changing the default behavior of a control is undesired. We went through this path in one of my project and results were not fruitful. `CheckBox` control is used for multi-selection unlike the radio button. I would suggest you to write a custom `RadioButtonCell` for the `DataGridView`.

This [Build a Custom RadioButton Cell and Column for the DataGridView Control](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa730882%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) article is nice place to start.

Comment: can you provide me dll. or sample solution, of  that grid which u have built.

Comment: Which one you are asking? The `DataGridView` with `CheckBoxColumn` behaving like radio button? I don't have it as we replaced it with the custom `RadioButtonCell` from the MSDN link.

Comment: okay then send me your custom RadioButtonCell content. , solution. you can share the link on mail2friends565@gmail.com, you can share me the dropbox link.

Answer (score 0):

Paste this code on datagridview `cellcontentclick` and it will work as radio button

```
        int row_index = e.RowIndex;
        for (int i = 0; i < dataGridView1.Rows.Count; i++)
        {
            if (row_index != i)
            {
                dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells["Column1"].Value = false;
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

None of the answers worked for me, so:

```
    private void MyDataGridView_CellMouseDown(object sender, DataGridViewCellMouseEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.RowIndex > -1 && myDataGridView.Columns["MyRadioButtonColumnName"].Index == e.ColumnIndex)
        {
            int rowsCount = myDataGridView.Rows.Count - (myDataGridView.AllowUserToAddRows ? 1 : 0);
            for (int rowIdx = 0; rowIdx < rowsCount; rowIdx++)
            {
                myDataGridView.Rows[rowIdx].Cells[e.ColumnIndex].Value = rowIdx == e.RowIndex;
            }                                    
        }
    }

    private void MyDataGridView_CellContentClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.RowIndex > -1 && myDataGridView.Columns["MyRadioButtonColumnName"].Index == e.ColumnIndex)
        {
            myDataGridView.CancelEdit();
        }
    }

    private void MyDataGridView_CellPainting(object sender, DataGridViewCellPaintingEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.RowIndex > -1 && myDataGridView.Columns["MyRadioButtonColumnName"].Index == e.ColumnIndex)
        {
            bool isSelected = myDataGridView.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[e.ColumnIndex].Selected;
            e.PaintBackground(e.ClipBounds, isSelected);

            if (e.RowIndex < myDataGridView.Rows.Count - 1 || myDataGridView.AllowUserToAddRows == false)
            {
                bool isChecked = Convert.ToBoolean(myDataGridView.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[e.ColumnIndex].Value) == true;
                RadioButtonState state = isChecked ? RadioButtonState.CheckedNormal : RadioButtonState.UncheckedNormal; // using System.Windows.Forms.VisualStyles                        
                RadioButtonRenderer.DrawRadioButton(e.Graphics, new Point(e.CellBounds.X + e.CellBounds.Width / 2 - 6, e.CellBounds.Y + e.CellBounds.Height / 2 - 6), state);
            }
            e.Handled = true;
        }
    }
```