# I need to allow user to check only one checkbox in all three columns checkboxes added in datagridview C#

Tags: c#, datagridview

I have a datagridview which i load from a datatable.
i manually add three columns via DataGridViewCheckBoxCell class.
Each row will be updated according to the checkbox checked by users.
i am facing problem how to restrict user to select or check one checkbox from all the three available in the selected row in the loaded datagridview.

The problem would be solved if there was an option of radio button adding in datagridview column or could i add a group of 3 radiobuttons as a column for each row.

[This is what my datagrid looks like after adding 3 datagridviewcheckboxCells](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jIq6k.png)

My code snippet of adding columns is

```
if (DG.DataSource != null)
                {
                    DataGridViewCheckBoxColumn ChbColReceived = new DataGridViewCheckBoxColumn();
                    DataGridViewCheckBoxColumn ChbColCancelled = new DataGridViewCheckBoxColumn();
                    DataGridViewCheckBoxColumn ChbColStop = new DataGridViewCheckBoxColumn();
                    DG.Columns.Add(ChbColReceived);
                    DG.Columns.Add(ChbColCancelled);
                    DG.Columns.Add(ChbColStop);
                    ChbColReceived.HeaderText = "Received";
                    ChbColCancelled.HeaderText = "Cancelled";
                    ChbColStop.HeaderText = "Stopped";
                }
```

### Your suggestion will be appreciable.
Regards

***Solution:***
Thanks to all devs/Gurus who helped me out. Special thanks to @JohnG whos answer is ticked as well. I have changed it a bit that may be acceptable for the person who answered. Here is my code which have solved my problem.

```
private void DG_CurrentCellDirtyStateChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                int colIndex = DG.CurrentCell.ColumnIndex;
                int rowIndex = DG.CurrentCell.RowIndex;
                bool currentValue;
                if (DG.Columns[colIndex].Index == 11 || DG.Columns[colIndex].Index == 12 || DG.Columns[colIndex].Index == 13)
                {
                    DG.CurrentCellDirtyStateChanged -= new EventHandler(DG_CurrentCellDirtyStateChanged);
                    currentValue = !(bool)DG.Rows[rowIndex].Cells[colIndex].FormattedValue;
                    switch (DG.Columns[colIndex].Index)
                    {
                        case 11:
                            if (currentValue == true)
                            {
                                DG.Rows[rowIndex].Cells[12].Value = false;
                                DG.Rows[rowIndex].Cells[13].Value = false;
                            }
                            break;
                        case 12:
                            if (currentValue == true)
                            {
                                DG.Rows[rowIndex].Cells[11].Value = false;
                                DG.Rows[rowIndex].Cells[13].Value = false;
                            }
                            break;
                        case 13:
                            if (currentValue == true)
                            {
                                DG.Rows[rowIndex].Cells[11].Value = false;
                                DG.Rows[rowIndex].Cells[12].Value = false;
                            }
                            break;
                    }
                    DG.CommitEdit(DataGridViewDataErrorContexts.Commit);
                    DG.CurrentCellDirtyStateChanged += new EventHandler(DG_CurrentCellDirtyStateChanged);
                }
            }
            catch (Exception) { throw; }
        }
```

The Col[11],Col[12],col[13] are my target checkboxed columns.
Thanks @JohnG for your time and concern.

Comment: You can make it in item model ... basically inside setters if value is true then set other bool values to false ... binding should do the thing(as long as `INotifyPropertyChanged` is implemented)

Comment: Are you able to change the datatable classes themselves? Since it is a datatable, I am assuming you will store the information as well? Normally I would use an enumeration property (a single field) and bind the 3 checkbox columns to helper properties that update that single field. That ensures only one checkbox can be true

Comment: It is not surprising that you are getting erratic results. The posted code in the `CurrentCellDirtyStateChanged` checks “EACH” check box cell starting at 11 then 12 then 13. This will not work. You ONLY want to check the value of the “changed” check box. The other “unchanged” check boxes are irrelevant so it is unnecessary to check them. When you change them in the order that you are, then this can happen… trace the code and you will see that…

Comment: If you start the app, all check boxes on the first row are not checked. The user clicks the check box in cell 13. The event fires… The code checks cell 11’s value… it is not true and is skipped, same for cells 12 AND also 13. Remember, this event fires “BEFORE” the check box is changed. Therefore, the first time it is fired, all if conditions will return false. Continuing execution leaves the event and sets the check box in cell 13 to true.

Comment: Now with cell 13 checked, the user clicks on the cell 11 check box. The event fires, Since the check box value in 11 has NOT been set yet, the first if statement checking cell 11 will be false. The cell at 12 will also be false. However, the current state of cell 13 is true and will set cells 11 and 12  to false. Then execution leaves the event THEN cell 11 is set to true. Here, you end up with cells 11 and 13 being checked at the same time.

Comment: As my answer does… you ONLY want to check the cell that was changed. And bear in mind that the value you are looking at is the NEGATION of the value it will be when it leaves the event. Your code appears to be missing this subtle change AFTER the event executes.

Comment: @JohnG Yes you are right but this is my requirement as well. my columns are also priority wise. received ,cancelled and stopped. I faces issues, it let user check more than one at a time but after user leave it applies its priority and checked the one on left side.
Actually i can make it better if i found the event that is fired after the checkbox value changed. after posting this answer i made some changes and checked for null as at the first fire it is null instead of bool value. 
then it worked with .Value instead of .FormattedValue property.

Comment: _“Actually i can make it better if i found the event that is fired after the checkbox value changed.”_ … this event is the `CellValueChanged` event, however, it will NOT execute the code in the event until the user “leaves” the cell. Also, I am confused by your comment, you can tell “what” value the check box will be... in the current event by NEGATING its current value. Obviously there is more to this than you are telling us.

Comment: Dear @JohnG . I have just copied you code and run my app. It let user check any of three checkboxes. I usually do not use any others dev code. I just get help. but I thought to apply your code as you were very much sure about it. but unfortunately your code couldn't do what my requirements were. I have snap shot. how can I send it to you ?
One thing more is that: i don't want to change my column of Current_Status here in the grid. I have some other plans. Your code may concentrate on changing the Current_State cell value.

Comment: I mean no disrespect, however, from you comment… _”unfortunately your code couldn't do what my requirements were”_ … ? What are your requirements? You keep changing them as we go along. If you take the time to make it clear “what” you want from the start, it will be easier for you and anyone who helps. Continuously changing the requirements is just annoying.

Comment: Your requirements are still NOT clear. However, according to the title of your question _”I need to allow user to check only one checkbox in all three columns checkboxes added in datagridview C#”_ … my code does exactly that. So, can you make up your mind as to “what” you want to do. It will be easier for everybody.

Comment: Dear @JohnG . Finally i modified your code and it started working with [column].index as it was not working in my environment with  [column].Name . After this modification your logic turns all things the way i wanted. You are my teacher from now onward. A great discussion with you will be remembered. I am updating my answer as well and posting my code that worked which is a bit modified form of your logic and code. Love You Sir.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several ways to achieve this, however a brute force approach would be to wire up the grids `CurrentCellDirtyStateChanged` event. This event will fire BEFORE the check box has changed its value, however we can still use it to determine what the current state of the check box is. The logic goes something like…

Check to see if the cell changed is one of the check box cells. If it is, then check its value by NEGATING its current value like…

```
currentValue = !(bool)dataGridView1.Rows[rowIndex].Cells[colIndex].FormattedValue;
```

Note the “!” negation here as whatever value it currently is, it will change to the negated value when we leave this event. From here, we simply check if the new value is `true`, if it is, then we want to set the other check boxes to `false`. This can be done with a simple `switch/case` statement.

It should be noted that since the code is possibly “changing” the other check box values, we need to turn this event OFF BEFORE we set those values to avoid any kind of re-entrant.

Below is a simple example of what is described above. I manually added the columns/rows to the grid, however, it should still work if the grid is data bound.

[image]

```
private void dataGridView1_CurrentCellDirtyStateChanged(object sender, EventArgs e) {
  int colIndex = dataGridView1.CurrentCell.ColumnIndex;
  int rowIndex = dataGridView1.CurrentCell.RowIndex;
  bool currentValue;
  string status = "Pending";
  if (dataGridView1.Columns[colIndex].Name == "Received" ||
      dataGridView1.Columns[colIndex].Name == "Canceled" ||
      dataGridView1.Columns[colIndex].Name == "Stopped") {
    dataGridView1.CurrentCellDirtyStateChanged -= new EventHandler(dataGridView1_CurrentCellDirtyStateChanged);
    currentValue = !(bool)dataGridView1.Rows[rowIndex].Cells[colIndex].FormattedValue;
    switch (dataGridView1.Columns[colIndex].Name) {
      case "Received":
        if (currentValue == true) {
          dataGridView1.Rows[rowIndex].Cells["Canceled"].Value = false;
          dataGridView1.Rows[rowIndex].Cells["Stopped"].Value = false;
          status = "Received";
        }
        break;
      case "Canceled":
        if (currentValue == true) {
          dataGridView1.Rows[rowIndex].Cells["Received"].Value = false;
          dataGridView1.Rows[rowIndex].Cells["Stopped"].Value = false;
          status = "Canceled";
        }
        break;
      case "Stopped":
        if (currentValue == true) {
          dataGridView1.Rows[rowIndex].Cells["Received"].Value = false;
          dataGridView1.Rows[rowIndex].Cells["Canceled"].Value = false;
          status = "Stopped";
        }
        break;
    }
    dataGridView1.Rows[rowIndex].Cells["CurrentStatus"].Value = status;
    dataGridView1.CommitEdit(DataGridViewDataErrorContexts.Commit);
    dataGridView1.CurrentCellDirtyStateChanged += new EventHandler(dataGridView1_CurrentCellDirtyStateChanged);
  }
}
```

Comment: Dear @JohnG : Thank you so much for the hard work you did to help me out. actually i was thinking all the dat about this. the whole solution is fantastic but the actual point i got from your answer was CurrentCellDirtyStateChanged event. i planned a solution for this using the same event , i will share it if it worked and you will like it as well. if that didn't work then your solution is already the best one. I will update my question and will inform you. Thank you so much.

Comment: Kindly check the question i have edited it and put the solution there using your tips.

Answer (score 1):

FYI , Radio buttons does this process by default, we use radio buttons for selecting gender. we can select any one option. you can use this default process for selecting any one of theree columns. use checkboxes as radio buttons.

[check this stackoverflow solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22471757/in-datagridview-how-to-use-checkbox-as-radiobutton)

Comment: Dear Jerry king as i mentioned and shown in the pic as well, radiobutton solution will be a better one but thats so costly and involves huge crap code as well. i went through the solution but that's not matching my requirements. i need 3 radio buttons in one cell and that becomes too much hard to manage. thanks for your concern.